# Indoor localization in my Android application

Tags: indoor-positioning-system

I am developing an Android app known as "ParkAssist" that will help user to navigate inside the indoor Parking space.The problem is I cannot use GPS system as it is an indoor application and have to rely on Wifi Fingerprinting.
I tried NN and K-NN approach for the localization but the results were extremely bad.Can anyone suggest me the better approach/algorithm for the same purpose so that I can get an accuracy of 5-10m.

Answer (score 1):

For my master's thesis I've developed an indoor localisation system using magnetic field changes. Worked very well for me. Only problem I see is that cars use a lot of ferromagnetic materials and therefore change the field too much. Basically the difference between a full and a empty parking construction could be too big. But at least have a look.

Comment: But how? Magnetic field changes only give you the directions. How to estimate the traveled distance?

Comment: I used a robot which was able to determine it's location to measure and map the magnetic fields at a ton of different locations within the space. Then I used a particle filter to locate and track the observed measurements onto this map.

Comment: Did you use only the magnetic fields of the environment or some of your own emitters?

Comment: We used the magnetic fields and existing WiFi networks